# facebook static fbml problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

I am facing a big big problem with adding a static page to my fan page, so i created a fan page using **static FBML**. Now *here* the problem starts.

> when i go to **edit page**, and then select apps.The apps section is
>   **totally empty**, tab is created  but why i cant see any app or
>   specially my static FBMLpage.

any suggestions for my problem?

[image: Empty apps section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static FBML pages have been deprecated so if this is a new page that could explain why.  You will be best off creating an iframe fan page tab.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/Static.FBMLs?sk=wall this is an iframe, but i cant see it my apps,

Comment: the above link is of statuc fbml 2011 which im using

Comment: Its deprecated for new apps (you can't create new ones). Existing apps still work, for now: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: This is a bug on Facebook at the moment, you should be able to use existing FBML apps (such as the Static.FBMLs app linked above)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at the Apps tab of the profile settings page. You could not be seeing anything because you haven't added any application to your personal profile. Did you create the application or are you just trying to at it to a page you created?

Comment: dude i added a page using static fbml,

Comment: the "Apps" tab is for Apps like Photos, Links, Events, Notes, etc... because your page isn't using those apps you don't see anything in that tab. Can you explain how you added a page using static fbml? Did you create a static fbml facebook application?

Comment: Actually its a bug with Facebook. I just made a page and when I added a static fbml page as you did the apps tab went blank.

Comment: sure, i used static fbml 2011, i liked it, there was an option 'add to page', i added it, a new fbml page is created(static fbml), you can see in this fan page(http://www.facebook.com/pages/Jawad-Saleem/243987732287726), so now when i go to edit page, and select apps, i should be seeing fbml page so that i can edit it, but there is nothing in that section to see as its empty

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I did. Definitely a bug.